# Finding the previous nameservers for a domain

Tags: domain-name-system

We are investigating an issue we had with DNS lookups to a specific domain (nyc.gov).

Does anyone know of a tool or website to find out the previous nameservers of a domain? We suspect the nameservers changed sometime this week and we want to verify that suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to [this](http://www.domaintools.com/hosting-history/?q=nyc.gov)?

Comment: +1 nice option. However, (of course) this is one time use. Going to keep this one in my back pocket for the time being. Let's see if I could find a free option. All I'll need is the NS records from about 2 weeks ago.